# What is a fiendish servant for Bleed for your master spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

What is a fiendish servant in the game? Do summons with the fiendish template count? The spell [Bleed for your master](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/bleed-for-your-master/) doesnt really say anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fiendish servant is the [antipaladin's](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/alternate-classes/antipaladin/) mount, which is kind of parallel to a paladin's mount granted from their Divine Bond. An antipaladin may gain a fiendish servant at 5th level.

> Fiendish Boon (Sp)
>
> Upon reaching 5th level, an antipaladin receives a boon from his dark patrons. This boon can take one of two forms. Once the form is chosen, it cannot be changed.

(skipping ahead, emphasis added by me)

> The second type of bond allows an antipaladin to gain the service of a **fiendish servant**. This functions as summon monster III, except the duration is permanent and the antipaladin can only gain the service of a single creature and that creature must either have the chaotic and evil subtypes or it must be a fiendish animal. Once selected, the choice is set, but it may be changed whenever the antipaladin gains a level...

Answer (score 3):

**See "Fiendish Boon" for Antipaladins**

At 5th level, Antipaladin's gain the Fiendish Boon power - this allows either a fiendish spirit to boost a weapon or *the summoning of a fiendish servant*.  See p 121-122 of the Advanced Players Guide.  The Fiendish Boon power is the "bad" equivalent of the paladin's Divine Bond power.

(Just a hint - look at the classes and context for this type of spell.  Here we have a spell that can only be cast on "*your* animal companion, familiar or fiendish servant".  The first two are well-known class features, so it follows that the third is too.  Then look at which classes can cast the spell and check their class features.)